# How can I separate POST requests by content-type?

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I want to execute different actions depending on the client-provided content-type. I've configured 2 controller actions for this:

```
/**
 * @Post("", requirements={"_format": "json"})
 */
public function postJsonAction(Request $request)
{
    // 
}

/**
 * @Post("", requirements={"_format": "csv"})
 */
public function postCsvAction(Request $request)
{
    //
}
```

However, this is not working for me, first action is always executed. What am I doing wrong here?
Here is my fos_rest configuration in the config.yml:

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    allowed_methods_listener: true
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
        include_format: false
    view:
        mime_types: { 'csv': ['text/csv'], 'xlsx': ['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'] }
        formats:
            json: true
            csv: true
            xlsx: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json', 'csv', 'xlsx'], fallback_format: ~, exception_fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
    service:
        view_handler: app.view_handler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure this in your route. For example, if you are using a yml route configuration.

```
csv:
    path:      /article/format/csv/
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Article:postCsv }

json:
    path:      /article/format/json/
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Article:postJson }
```

Then, using JS to change your form action.

```
if ("csv" === $("#format").val()) {
   $('#your_form').attr('action', '/article/format/csv/');
}
else {
   $('#your_form').attr('action', '/article/format/json/');
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use already available content-type without creating named endpoints like `/article/format/csv/`?

Comment: As far as I understand, routes are dependant on GET, not POST, so any solution you have will need to convert from one to the other.